# How to turn off Background Audio Agents in Windows Phone 7.5?

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio, background, agent

I'm following this [Hands on Lab](https://docs.google.com/open?id=1WjSDA6auaX8oko7nnCAuE_YYBUagu65P1XqrqxAmsUVSvObUgjj9iG3U4Tt4)

And then I've a small question: how to turn off this program completely?
I tried: BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Close();
but it stills running. I wanna remove this control when program is turned off.

See [this picture](https://docs.google.com/viewer?pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESj7L5tvkEIed7ZwCP7F_HKDoZ8dMpGBH85j0g2PUtGuPq2KA6jB7j-3Ot3uf-Bk8TGFP9FIdpFQhitMsKX871vylsNO5ppj2_8MS4rn23B5P_M2dEcXZTN78JoO74rQua2D5BFj&q=cache%3az_VvyMYOaLcJ%3aaz12722.vo.msecnd.net/windowsphonetrainingcourse1-5-2/labs/musicplayerlab1-0-0/MusicPlayer.docx%20&docid=9b102da23a9d3dcb2bc43105fb3fcc9f&a=bi&pagenumber=25&w=800). thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

`BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Stop()` ?

Also, [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpukcoe/archive/2012/02/09/background-audio-in-windows-phone-7-5-part-1.aspx) 3 part series is really good.

Answer (score 0):

I use `BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Close()` and the agent is shut down

> Closes the player and removes all resources reserved for it, including
>   the current AudioTrack.

You can see the Shut down event is fired in `OnPlayStateChanged` event handler

Also, when seeing at the Output window, the Background Task is terminated